# Как регуляркой вытащить значение такого вида: $Q1?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение. Нужно из строки такого вида вытаскивать значения после $

```
($Q1==1)and($Q4o=="55")and($Q1o1=="")
```

А именно: `$Q1`, `$Q4o`, `$Q1o1`

Т.е. условие регулярки начинается с `$` и заканчивается любым символом кроме `A-Za-z0-9_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$value = '($Q1==1)and($Q4o=="55")and($Q1o1=="")';
preg_match_all('#\(\$(.*?)\)#i',$value, $match);
var_dump($match);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "($Q1==1)"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "($Q4o=="55")"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "($Q1o1=="")"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Q1==1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Q4o=="55""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Q1o1=="""
  }
}
```

Comment: а, понял, ща.

Comment: спасибо ребят, но на стековерфлове поделились замечательным выражением из 7 символов, и оно работает)  

/\$\w*/

Comment: Я вообще думал, вам нужно что-то вроде: '#\(\$(\w+[^a-z0-9_]{1})==(?:.*?)\)#i'
В следующий раз объясняйте правильней, что хотите получить :-) А то мы пыжимся, а толку ноль.

Answer (score 2):

Банальное `'/(\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/'`, нет?

Comment: нене, тут во-первых стоит указать, что выражение стоит брать в одинарные кавычки, а во-вторых тут прикол в том, что ПОСЛЕДНЯЯ буква должна [^A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: А я так понял, что пока `[A-Za-z0-9]` — это часть токена, принимаем символ. Как только нет — закончилось. Если бы последняя была `[^A-Za-z0-9]`, у него было бы `["$Q1=", "$Q4o=", "$Q1o1="]`.

Comment: спасибо ребят, но на стековерфлове поделились замечательным выражением из 7 символов, и оно работает)  

/\$\w*/